# GeoJson layer not visible on python Folium map

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I am trying to add a GeoJSON layer to a Folium map but the layer is not visible in the map though it is visible in the layer selector of folium. I am able to view the data in Qgis so the data is correct. I also do not get an error in Spyder.

I also inspected the HTML in the browser and there seems to be a script added with all the coordinates etc. The browser does not display an error when inspecting the file.

Anyone an idea what I am missing?

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(
    location=[-59.1759, -11.6016],
    tiles='OpenStreetMap',
    zoom_start=2  # Limited levels of zoom for free Mapbox tiles.
)

folium.GeoJson(
    data=(open('./projects/test/data/breda_bus_route.geojson', "r").read()),
    name='layerName',

).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save('index.html')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be case that GeoJSON layer is not visible since it's not fit within the given map view, try to dynamically fit GeoJSON layer to the map view:

```
layer = folium.GeoJson(
    data=(open(path, "r").read()),
    name='geojson',

).add_to(m) # 1. keep a reference to GeoJSON layer


m.fit_bounds(layer.get_bounds())  # 2. fit the map to GeoJSON layer
```

**Update**

It appears it was related with GeoJSON file projection `EPSG::3857`, Leaflet expects `EPSG:4326`.

Once GeoJSON reprojected, the layer will be rendered like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be to simply use EPSG:4326 - WSG 84 when exporting the layer to GeoJSON in Qgis. This is actually the coordinate system (CRS) most web maps use and was mentioned in the edit.

I also recommend setting the coordinate_precision to 5 for a lighter file, 5 digit precision in the coordinates is usually more than enough for web visualizations. 15 is definitely not necessary.

[image]